# How to write a condition for element which is not present in an array

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfif

I want this code to be executed if the array `s` does not contain the element in `curr` variable. How do I need to modify the if condition?

```
<cfif s.contains(#curr#)>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(s,curr)>
    <cfset en++>
    <cfset cl=en-st>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Did you try omitting the hashtags in your condition?  Like this `<cfif s.contains(curr)>`

Comment: How about adding `not` in front of `s.contains(`? Note that using Java methods like `List.contains` might yield surprising results when working with numbers as those methods are type sensitive contrary to ColdFusion's internal casting. So you are better off using ColdFusion's `arrayFind` or `arrayFindNoCase`.

Comment: What version of CF? Can you just use a safe navigation or Elvis?  `if(s?.curr)` or `if(s?:curr)`?

Comment: Never mind. Just realized you were working with an array. Those don't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is ArrayFind.  Documentation is here ==> https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayfind.html

You want something like this:

```
<cfif ArrayFind(s, curr) is 0>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(s,curr)>
    <cfset en++>
    <cfset cl=en-st>
</cfif>
```